# Find the element in custom array and append the value in one of its property(which is also an array) of custom array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, model

```
@objc class CplModel:NSObject {
    var cplModel:UserCplModel = UserCplModel(json: [:])
    var courseData:[CourseModel] = [CourseModel]()
    var feedData:[FeedsModel] = [FeedsModel]()
    var assessmentData:[AssessmentModel] = [AssessmentModel]()
    var userCourseData:[UserCourseModel] = [UserCourseModel]()

    init(jsonUserCPlModel:[String:Any]){
        if let value  = jsonUserCPlModel[""] as? [String:Any]{
            self.cplModel = UserCplModel(json: value)
        }
    }

    init(jsonAssessmentAndCourseData:[String]) {
    }
}
```

I am making three Firebase calls and all three are interlinked and want to populate data in above model.

Here comes the issue:

- For 1st API call I need to populate only `cplModel:UserCplModel` property
- For 2nd ApI call I need to populate  `courseData:[CourseModel]` and `assessmentData:[AssessmentModel]`

But the index should remain the same for every populating data.
I mean to say is for 1st index of `cplModel`, I need to insert the `courseData` or `assessmentData` but the response of 2nd API comes later and I need to insert the data in particular index only.

Comment: Supposed that you know the index of the item you are going to modify. Dump it to a var and modify its attribute, then call `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` to replace that item with new one.

Comment: what do you mean by " I mean to say is for 1st index of cplModel,"  I dont' see an array of cplModel